# How to authenticate app to act as if it was my logged in google account

Tags: python, google-api, google-signin, google-authentication

I have written scripts connecting to the google API to connect to bigquery and google sheets and slides.

However, currently I am trying to write a script that would be able to access a non-google site for which I am required to be signed in with my gmail account to access.

So essentially when I access this site in a browser, I am asked to login using gmail and allow the site to verify my details, and in return I can view the page. If I don't login with google I cannot view the page.

I am not sure how/if the google authentication process for my app could be set up in a way for it to login as if it was myself. But can anybody give me some advice on how I can get my app to pass the google sign-in process, so that my app can access the contents of the website?

Please let me know if I can clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: There is so much we would need to know to help you. Do you want to log in via an automated browser instance (via something like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer))? If not, what type of [authorization grant flow](https://medium.com/@robert.broeckelmann/saml2-vs-jwt-understanding-oauth2-4abde9e7ec8b) does the non-Google authorizer follow? Does the non-Google site have any limits or safeguards against programmatic login? (Would they be okay with what you have planned?)

Answer (score 0):

If choosing not to use Google API is okay, and if it is only one specific website that you would like to access, then I would suggest looking into doing this using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). You can simulate the way you use the browser so the script can do it for you. [Here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/automate-create-login-bot-python-selenium/)  is a tutorial on a simple login use-case that might be relevant to your problem.
Hope it helps.